# nc command and iptables on CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I have practised in using iptables on CentOS 7 (It is a guest machine on Virtual Box). At first I disabled `firewalld`:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Then I installed iptables:

```
yum -y install iptables-services
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
```

After all this I tried to open tcp-port on my local machine with `nc -l 1025` command but command just hung up. I was looking all over the Internet and found out that I could flush iptables rules in this post [The netcat command can't access an open port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98939/the-netcat-command-cant-access-an-open-port) but after this I had no connection to the Internet at all. So I returned my CentOS7 in previous state when I had just installed iptables. Here is my iptables's rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state    RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp    dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with  icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is the verbose mode of `nc -vl 1025`:

```
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::1025
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:1025
```

And the result of `ss -lnt`:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer    Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*
LISTEN     0      100               127.0.0.1:25                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*
LISTEN     0      100                     ::1:25                      :::*
```

Another verbose mode for example for port 2000 `nc -vl 2000`:

```
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::2000
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:2000
```

the result of `ss -lnt` is the same:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer  Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*
LISTEN     0      100               127.0.0.1:25                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*
LISTEN     0      100                     ::1:25                      :::*
```

So what am I going to do to make my `nc` command works properly and I can open some tcp port on CentOS7?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hang up'? By default `netcat` starts and does nothing visible, and stays that way. Is that what happens? If it's so, doesn't port `1025` show in output of `ss -lnt`?

Comment: @TNW, I edited my answer and added your `ss` command. 'Hung up' means that after typing `nc -l 1025` and press ENTER nothing happened and  I didn't saw another line as `[root@localhost ~]#`

Comment: Just to make sure, you're using `ss` while `nc` is still running, right? If so, thats kind of weird. As far as I know, any `iptables` rules can't prevent you from listening. This looks more like SELinux thing to me - maybe try `getenforce`, and it it's set to 'Enforcing', do `setenforce 0` and check again (if you can afford turning disabling SELinux for a while).

Comment: Well, I opened one console and typed `nc -l 1026`, then I opened another one and typed `nc localhost 1026` everything worked like if it was correct, but when I typed `ss -lnt` in third console I had what I wrote in my answer: no ports were listening on - 1026 for example.

Comment: That's because `ncat` listens only once. After you connected to it with client, it's not listening for any other connection attempts Try without `nc localhost 1026`.

Comment: Now everything is clear, you can post it in answer!Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solved in the comments - quick summary of the most important points:

- `ncat`, and possibly other `netcat` impletmentations, listens for incoming connection only once, and stops doing so with the first attempt (unless there's a switch in program for that)
- programs can start listening on a port regardless of what are the current iptables settings