# Port 443 switching to filtered after openssl test

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, openssl, ssl, nmap

While I was investigating [this issue related to SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510166/my-website-not-responding-with-ssl) (published as OT in StackOverflow), I found a curious behaviour.

#### Premise

The premise is that I was trying to understand why my web server (hosted on a CentOs 6 VPS on which runs a web based application) doesn't reply when accessing as `https://my.site.com` while the same website reply correctly at a `http://my.site.com`. The Apache 2.2 running on the VPS *should* have been correctly configured to listen to port 443.

#### The strange behaviour

Let's see the following sequence of outputs. I run the following three commands from a shell to check port 443 of the *remote* server, let's say my.site.com at IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. I masked out some specific information

```
# nmap -p443 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-07 23:32 CET
Nmap scan report for [some-host] (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.16 seconds

# openssl s_client -connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
3069269200:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1483830497
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

# nmap -p443 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-08 00:08 CET
Nmap scan report for [some-host] (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
Host is up (0.064s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.25 seconds
```

It seems that port 443 becomes *filtered* for nmap just after I run OpenSSL. How is this possible? What could be the reason for that behaviour?

#### Edit

the `openssl` command run locally on the remote server gives the following output, so it seems that certificates are correctly configured (please tell me if I'm wrong):

```
# openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = [some CA], CN = [some CA] Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = [some CA], CN = [some CA] X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = my.site.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=my.site.com
   i:/C=US/O=[some CA]/CN=[some CA] X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=[some CA]/CN=[some CA] X3
   i:/O=[some CA]/CN=[some CA] Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[some data]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=my.site.com
issuer=/C=US/O=[some CA]/CN=[some CA] X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3672 bytes and written 373 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: F2F71647F95F40CA29C5AA8628D76B466C8B89CFF5A1992B88DDC121FB376345
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: [some data]
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [some data]

    Start Time: 1483840507
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Don't you see that your SSL is not configured properly and showing it's missing the certificates?

Comment: "443 becomes filtered for nmap just after I run openssl." => I may be wrong but it seems to me it got filtered after you ran _nmap_ ("SSL handshake has read 0 bytes"). Even if the SSL connection succeeded,  by repeatedly scanning the ports, you may have triggered a security measure that blocks you at the firewall level. `telnet host port` or `nc host port` are far enough to test an open port, don't use an aggressive beast like nmap.

Comment: @Julie, ok i'm not an expert, but if I run the same `openssl` command locally on the remote server, it seems to me that the it replies correctly. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510166/my-website-not-responding-with-ssl) post where tried it. Furthermore, if the certificates were missing why the state of port 443 changes after the openssl test?

Comment: Try `openssl s_client -connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443` from the server itself and see if you get an error.

Comment: The answer to your question would be found on the remote server but I think you are mostly interested in getting `HTTPS` working, right?

Comment: @Julie, I put in the 'edit' section the output of the openssl command run locally on the remote server. Yes now I want to get HTTPS working.

Comment: @Julie, the output was missing of some parts, now it's complete, sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: @xhienne, I didn't know that nmap was so aggressive, in effect trying `nc -zv XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 443` returns `Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!`. So it seems that port 443 works correctly, so  at least it seems it's listened by the server....

Comment: @mpogg Especially when you run `nmap` as root, like you did, Priviledged nmap sends specially crafted frames using raw sockets. As a regular user, with your `-p443` option, nmap is more innocuous (it still scans port 80 whereas there is no additional `-p80` option). Anyway, you'd better avoid using it on a public site (like a VPS provider, even if the VPS is yours).

Comment: ok. Furthermore it seems that CentOS comes with default iptables rules which blocks all connections coming to any port other than 22 port. I used the `iptables -F` and all worked! Thanks to [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98939/the-netcat-command-cant-access-an-open-port).

Comment: @mpogg If such an iptable rule is in the way, why is it working for port 80? And why your [accept rule for https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510166/my-website-not-responding-with-ssl) is not working?

Comment: @mpogg And why your first `openssl s_client` command above succeeded in connecting (it wrote `CONNECTED(00000003)`)?

Comment: @xhienne, it seems that my stupid error was to put the rule specifying to accept the port 443 incoming request *after* the last rule that specifies to reject all the requests not matching any of the above. It is the only reason why port 443 was reasonably refused. I don't know why it responds at least once as `connected` when it *should be* refused. Anyway once the rules in iptables are set in the right order all works fine. Port 22 was enabled in iptables such as some other ports (like port 80) so is correct that all worked fine for port 80.